# Notification when someone connects to my PC

Tags: windows-7, shared-folders

I share out a folder on my windows 7 machine.  But, I would really like a notification to tell me when someone connects to it.  Or I would like to at least be able to check at any one time who is looking at it?

Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Start, right click Computer and choose Manage.

On the left side of the Computer Management window that appears expand the Shared Folders node. There you have three options:

- Shares shows you the folders currently shared on the machine
- Sessions shows you who is connected to those folders
- Open files shows who has what files open

To have a history of who accessed what and when, configure Windows 7 to log access to shared folders as Audit Events in the Event Log - follow [these instructions](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/123362-audit-log-access-shared-folders.html).

You can also get software that will allow you to monitor the shares such as [this](http://stevemiller.net/sharewatch/).

Comment: Brilliant answer